# cronjob not executing on macos

Tags: macos, cron

This should run once a day at 1 am:

```
0 1 * * * pod repo update | while IFS= read -r line; do printf '%s %s\n' "$(date)" "$line"; done >> /Users/ci/podRepoUpdate.log 2>&1
```

however the log (`/Users/ci/podRepoUpdate.log`) stays empty.

If I run the command

```
pod repo update | while IFS= read -r line; do printf '%s %s\n' "$(date)" "$line"; done >> /Users/ci/podRepoUpdate.log 2>&1
```

manually, it works. What am I missing here?

Comment: For scheduling jobs, you're better off using [launchd](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html). As the documentation states **Although it's still supported, cron is not a recommended solution. It has been deprecated in favor of lauchd**

Comment: In a crontab entry, `%` works a bit like a newline character unless you escape it. To avoid dealing with this messiness, I'd recommend putting the command in a shell script, and just running that from cron (or better yet, launchd).

Comment: Actually I have been using launchd, but I'm more familiar with unix cron jobs. That's why I want to use regular cron jobs. @GordonDavisson thanks for the hint with %. I put the commands in a shell script and now they work. If you put your comment as an answer, I'm happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the command in an shell script worked, as suggested by [Gordon Davidsson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson). This is my crontab now:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

0 1 * * * /Users/ci/podRepoUpdate.sh
```

The shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

pod repo update | ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]' >> /Users/ci/podRepoUpdate.log 2>&1
```